# Updating Vendors Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Hi I donwloaded and installed Symfony2 using the archive but I had a problem during the vendor's updating.
In my principal folder Symfony I run the command `php composer.phar install` but I obtained the following error

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.0].

What can I do?

Comment: Pretty sure those errors are telling you the exact problem

Comment: the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system

Comment: what os are you running what webserver wrapper are you running how did you install php

Comment: run the check script (php app/check.php) and activate fix all ERRORS

Comment: I running Ubuntu 14.04 with an Apache/2.4.7 and php 5.5.9

Comment: @AndyHolmes I have curl..

Comment: @P_R *"the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system"* says differently :/

Comment: @AndyHolmes I know but if I type cur on my terminal I obtained curl and curl-config

Comment: I reinstalled curl with che command sudo apt-get install php5-curl.
Now I obtain this error:
[RuntimeException]                                                       
  Unable to write in the cache directory (/var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev)  
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception              
  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.

Comment: This is another problem. You can find answer on that problem in google or on stackoverflow. Or maybe you can just read documentation and make your folders writable. Did you read documentation that I linked below?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install curl:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Then you need to restart your web-server

Comment: I reinstalled curl with che command sudo apt-get install php5-curl. Now I obtain this error: [RuntimeException] Unable to write in the cache directory (/var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev) Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception [RuntimeException] An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.

Comment: Now you need to make your cache and logs directories writable. Check the symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup