# Can't update composer.phar - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

When I try to update packages with the terminal command : `php composer.phar update` I have this error message

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- sensio/distribution-bundle v4.0.0 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.5, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4].
- sensio/distribution-bundle v4.0.0 requires sensiolabs/security-checker ~2.0 -> satisfiable by sensiolabs/security-checker[v2.0.5, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4].
- sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.4 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- Installation request for sensio/distribution-bundle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by sensio/distribution-bundle[v4.0.0]."
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @goto while the formatting of the question had been terrible until Jovan edited it.  The question seems to have all pieces, `Trying to update packages -> Using this command -> Getting this error message.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating Vendors Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482759/updating-vendors-symfony2)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from message: you need to install `ext-curl` extension for PHP.

To install it in Ubuntu you need to run next command:

```sh
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Don't forget to restart apache (or fpm) after it:

```sh
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or fpm:

```sh
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that sensio/distribution-bundle v4 requires sensiolabs/security-checker v2.0.x, which in turn requires the PHP curl extension, which is not installed.  So composer cannot (currently) fulfil the requirements specified in your composer.json.  At a basic level, you need to install the curl extension.

Why this happened in your case is difficult to determine without more detail:

- Have you recently upgraded from distribution bundle v3 to v4?  Looks like the dependency on security-checker was introduced between those.  You could possibly revert to v3 to avoid this issue.
- Has the PHP environment changed, to remove the curl extension?

Comment: Don't ask questions in Answer. You should comment it.